# Which one is correct–ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒɪz or ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒɪs?

Tags: phonetics, transcription

To me, it is expected to get /ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒɪz/ for *languages* in the phonemic transcription though the last consonant is completely voiceless in the pronunciation of the speakers [here](https://linguistics.berkeley.edu/acip/course/chapter2/exercises2/exercise2d.html). You can check it by looking at the [spectrogram](https://d3uxfe7dw0hhy7.cloudfront.net/acip/assets/course/chapter2/exercises2/exercise%20sounds/petersound%202d/languages.png).

So the question is, does it lead to the two possibilities–/ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒɪz/ and /ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒɪs/?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally accepted when the stem ends with a sibilant, the plural suffix is /ɪz/. However, many native speakers actually have a [final-obstruent devoicing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288730/unvoiced-d%CA%92-and-%CA%92-in-word-final-position), meaning that the /z/ is realized as [s] when directly followed by a silence or a voiceless consonant.

The transcription /ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒɪz/ is a phonemic transcription; it is not meant to be phonetically accurate and does not represent the actual sounds produced by the speakers. See [Phonemic vs Phonetic Transcription](http://australianlinguistics.com/speech-sounds/phonemic-vs-phonetic/).

Comment: @Aer I don't understand the first question. As for second one, I didn't say that only [z] was possible.

Comment: Sorry, it seems you didn't get the second too. I used /z/ notation, not [z]. I'll try to make it clear. The question is how do you prove that the phonemic transcription is /ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒɪz/, and /ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒɪs/ is wrong?